# How do I write a function's output to a file using iofstream?

Tags: c++

I'm working on an assignment that:

1. Prompts user for a year input no less than 1582.
2. Produces a file (cal.dat) containing the calendar produced by the code I write.

I wrote the code that takes input, calculates whether or not it's a leap year, and then gives back the calendar for that year with `cout`.

When I try to output the calendar to the file Xcode gives me this error in compiling:

```
Invalid operands to binary expression ('ofstream' (aka 'basic_ofstream<char>') and 'void')
```

A part of the code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void PrintMonth(int year, bool leap);
ofstream calendar("cal.dat"); 

int main()
{
    // Setting up the parameters for the PrintMonth function
    int year=0;
    bool leap=false;

    // Input for the year
    cout << "Enter a 4 digit year: ";
    cin >> year;

    // Loop for an incorrect entry
    while (year<1582)
        {
        cout << "Year too low, please re-enter: ";
        cin >> year;
        }

    // Calculate if the input year is a leap year or not
    if ((year%4==0 && year%100!=0) || year%400==0)
        leap=true;

    // Output the year and the calendar for the year requested
    calendar << setw(15) << year << endl << endl;
    calendar << PrintMonth(year, leap);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to add a stream parameter to `PrintMonth` and use that instead of `cout`.

Comment: `PrintMonth` returns `void`.... what exactly do you think you are writing to your `ofstream` when you call that function?

Comment: Voted to reopen because the questioner has given enough information for an answerer to give a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

you write `calendar << PrintMonth(year, leap)`, which would mean that you pass the return value of `PrintMonth` into `calendar`.
However, according to the signature `void PrintMonth(int year, bool leap)`, this function does not return a value which could be printed out.
Did you mean `PrintMonth(year,leap);` instead of `calendar << PrintMonth(year,leap)`?

So you could copy your `PrintMonth`-function, change the signature to `void PrintMonth(int year, bool leap, std::ostream& out)`, adapt its implementation to write to `out` instead of `cout`, and call `PrintMonth(year,leap, calendar);` instead of writing `calendar << PrintMonth(year,leap)`.

Comment: When I simply put PrintMonth(year, leap), the calendar prints out alright as if I used cout. The void function was something carried over from a previous assignment, so if I wanted it to return the things it prints out, should I turn it into an int function?

Comment: with an `int`-function, you can only return one int at a time, but not a sequence of "things it prints out". I'd suggest to change `PrintMonth` in a way that - instead of printing out something to console - it writes to `calendar`. So, copy the code of `PrintMonth` and change it accordingly.

Comment: I think a better suggestion would be to add another parameter (of type `std::ostream&`) to `PrintMonth`, and use that as the stream to print to inside the function, instead of printing to a global variable.

Comment: @Nenjamin Lindley: right, adapted the answer.